# django static annotation

Tags: python, django

I want to add a static value to the results of a database query using django (so not using 'raw' SQL)

For example, if I have an object Car with fields make, model, and color, then I want my results set with extra static value to look something like this:

```
make     model     color    sales
----     -----     -----    -----
nissan   bluebird  black    0
ford     fiesta    red      0
toyota   camry     green    0
```

I tried code like

```
cars= Car.objects.all().annotate(sales=0)
```

but got errors. What can I do?

Cheers,
Dave

--Trindaz on Fedang #django

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Update

This solution uses soon-to-be-deprecated API. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36719467/140185) for a better way to solve this.

#### Original Answer

You can use the [`extra()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) method. Like this:

```
Car.objects.all().extra(select = {'sales': 0})
```

Comment: "This is an old API that we aim to deprecate at some point in the future" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Answer (score 134):

Django features [`Value` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions):

```py
from django.db.models import Value

cars= Car.objects.annotate(sales=Value(0))
```

Prior to Django 3.2, specify the field class:

```py
from django.db.models import Value, IntegerField

cars= Car.objects.annotate(sales=Value(0, IntegerField()))
```

Instead of `IntegerField()` you can use instances of all available model fields (ex: `CharField()`, ...)

Comment: This is actually the better answer now. extra() is going to be, if not already deprecated.

Comment: When I use this approach (in Django 3.0) I find the `sales` column is being filled with `None` instead of `0`

Comment: This works for me in Django 3.2, simply using `.annotate=Value(0)`.